# Place gradient color inside UIView in tableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview, gradient

I have added two views inside a stack view. I am having that stack view inside my tableViewCell. Now my stackView is placed in the centre of the content view with width and height. I want to apply gradient color inside my view which is inside my stackView .

Just look at the view below In this case I am giving view a background colour of red and green which I don't want. I want to apply gradient of four colours to this views.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO4ul.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create GradientLayer on your tableViewCell(collectionViewCell)

#### 1. Create `CAGradientLayer` Instance on your `tableViewCell`

```swift
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
}
```

#### 2. Set the layer frame to view's bounds from `layoutSublayers(of:)`

If you set your layer's frame some other place, frame becomes weird.

```swift
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    // Setting it from layoutSubViews also fine.
    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: self.layer)
        gradientLayer.frame = yourView.bounds
    }
}
```

#### 3. Add GradientLayer on the View.

Here is my UIView extension for adding gradient layer.

```swift
extension UIView {
    func addGradient(with layer: CAGradientLayer, gradientFrame: CGRect? = nil, colorSet: [UIColor],
                     locations: [Double], startEndPoints: (CGPoint, CGPoint)? = nil) {
        layer.frame = gradientFrame ?? self.bounds
        layer.frame.origin = .zero

        let layerColorSet = colorSet.map { $0.cgColor }
        let layerLocations = locations.map { $0 as NSNumber }

        layer.colors = layerColorSet
        layer.locations = layerLocations

        if let startEndPoints = startEndPoints {
            layer.startPoint = startEndPoints.0
            layer.endPoint = startEndPoints.1
        }

        self.layer.insertSublayer(layer, above: self.layer)
    }
}
```

* Option 1 - Add it from `layoutSublayers(of:)`

```swift
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: self.layer)
        gradientLayer.frame = yourView.bounds
        
        let colorSet = [UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0),
                        UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)]
        let location = [0.2, 1.0]
        
        yourView.addGradient(with: gradientLayer, colorSet: colorSet, locations: location)
    }
}
```

* Option 2 - Add it from `cellForRowAt`

For example, if we have `cellForRowAt` and like this,

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCellId", for: indexPath) as? MyCell {
      cell.configureCell(content: someItems[indexPath.row])
  }
  return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Now, we can handle gradientLayer from `configureCell(content:)`.

```swift
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    func configureCell(content: YourType) {
        let colorSet = [UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0),
                        UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)]
        let location = [0.2, 1.0]
        yourView.addGradient(with: gradientLayer, colorSet: colorSet, locations: location)
    }
    
    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: self.layer)
        gradientLayer.frame = yourView.bounds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of a simple progress bar that I have written in Swift:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

public class GradientProgressView : NSView
{
    // MARK: - Fields
    private let bgLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private var progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    private var blockLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private var mValue: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    public var colors: [NSColor] = [NSColor.systemGreen, NSColor.systemYellow, NSColor.sytemRed]
    
    public var value: CGFloat
    {
        set
        {
            self.mValue = newValue
            
            if self.mValue > 1.0
            {
                self.mValue = 1.0
            }
            if self.mValue < 0.0 || self.mValue.isNaN || self.mValue.isInfinite
            {
                self.mValue = 0.0
            }
            
            self.progressLayer.strokeEnd = self.mValue
        }
        get
        {
            return self.mValue
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Overrides
    public override func layout()
    {
        super.layout()
        
        self.initialize()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Helper
    fileprivate func initialize()
    {
        self.wantsLayer = true
        
        self.layer?.masksToBounds = true // Optional
        self.layer?.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height / 2.0 // Optional
        
        self.bgLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        self.bgLayer.contentsScale = NSScreen.scale
        self.bgLayer.fillColor = NSColor.separatorColor.cgColor
        self.bgLayer.path = NSBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        self.layer?.addSublayer(self.bgLayer)
        
        self.blockLayer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.blockLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        
        let path = NSBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.height / 2.0, y: self.bounds.height / 2.0))
        path.line(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width - self.bounds.height / 2.0, y: self.bounds.height / 2.0))
        
        self.progressLayer.path = path.cgPath
        self.progressLayer.strokeColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
        self.progressLayer.fillColor = nil
        self.progressLayer.lineWidth = self.bounds.height
        self.progressLayer.lineCap = .round
        self.progressLayer.strokeStart = 0.0
        self.progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
        self.progressLayer.contentsScale = NSScreen.scale
        
        self.gradientLayer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        self.gradientLayer.contentsScale = NSScreen.scale
        self.gradientLayer.colors = self.colors.map({ $0.cgColor })
        self.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        self.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        self.gradientLayer.mask = self.progressLayer
        self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        self.gradientLayer.contentsScale = NSScreen.scale
        
        self.layer?.addSublayer(self.gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

This progress bar supports multiple colors.
Simply replace your progress bar logic with the one I posted above (or add the logic for the triangle that is shown below the progress bar).

Preview:

[image: Preview]